# If on specific URL, redirect to another URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tampermonkey

Using Tampermonkey for Chrome!

I am finally at the final issue with my code.   I have attempted a few different ways yet none of these are actually working for me :( (listed below)

What is the best way to check if on a specific URL and IF on that URL link, then redirect to another URL?

I have tried the code below.

As well as scouring google for anything else (which these are the only 2 that appear but neither actually say for tampermonkey)

```
if(window.location.href == "https://yahoo.com/news"){
    var MyURL = GM_getValue ("http://www.google.com/news");
    window.location.href = MyURL;
}

or

if(window.location.pathname === 'https://yahoo.com/news'){
    var MyURL = GM_getValue ("http://www.google.com/news");
    window.location.href = MyURL;
}
```

I am legitimately slamming my head on the desk as I have been trying to figure this out for the last 4 hours.

Comment: Yahoo is adding www here (`https://www.yahoo.com/news`) so I think you should try adding it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @wOxxOm said, yahoo adds a www.

Try:

```
if(window.location.href == "https://www.yahoo.com/news"){
   window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/news";
}
```

Also, if what you are trying to do is change a default webpage, there is probably a browser setting that you can change instead of using tempermonkey.

Comment: Awesome. If you could mark this has an answer in case someone else encounters the issue it would be appreciated.